# Kerberized Cluster remote connectivity using Python without using Kinit

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, kerberos, webhdfs

How do I transfer files using a python script from from a different system to a kerberized cluster , without using Kinit and creating a ticket in that terminal?I want to enable the authentication from the python script, I have the keytab file. I want to create a job that would directly dump files to HDFS from a remote system, without me trying to activate the ticket every time and then run the script.

Comment: You mean, how to connect to a secure system without any security? That would be kind of absurd if it was possible, don't you think ?

Comment: I have edited the question details.I want to enable the authentication from the python script, I have the keytab file. I want to create a job that would directly dump files to HDFS from a remote system, without me trying to activate the ticket every time and then run the script.

Comment: Possible workaround: from your Python code, set env variable `KRB5CCNAME` to a random file name, then run system command `kinit -kt <keytab_file> <user_principal>`, then connect to HDFS, then run `kdestroy` >> the env variable makes sure you don't use the default, shared ticket cache but instead a "private" file _(and env variables are inherited by sub-processes hence by `kinit` and `kdestroy`)_